# Weird SPListItem URL when adding a new announcement

Tags: sharepoint

When I add a new item in a default Announcement list using the GUI the new item looks just as I would expect, showing the title of the item in the breadcrumb. However when adding the new item through the object model:

SPList theList = web.Lists["announcement"];

SPListItem theitem = theList.Add();

theitem["Title"] = "this is the title";

theitem.Update();

then the breadcrumb will display something like
WebTitle.ListTitle.34_.000, which I believe to be the itemID and versionnumber of the item.

A search give [this](http://www.sharepointsecurity.com/blog/sharepoint/sharepoint-2007-development/splistitemurl-funky-return-fiesta/) but I would like to know the root cause and possible how to avoid the issue.

Comment: Are you sure that above code is the actual one you are using ?. Can you post the full code. So it will be helpful to sort out the issue.

Comment: The code is not the actual code as I can't access that code repository from home right now, sorry.

Comment: The code you've included should work fine. Also the article you've linked to appears unrelated - the URL of a list item doesn't determine the breadcrumb displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. Actually the list in question was a discussion list, not a announcement list ( why it was then named "announcement" is a big mystery), 
Since a discussion is actually a thread container and the threads within the container, I had to call [SPUtility.CreateNewDiscussion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.createnewdiscussion.aspx) rather then list.Add.